# I am not able to start my react server..i dont know what to do!! also removed cache and installed node modules again

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I was trying to start my react server, i have also tried to install node_modules but still the same problem is coming.

> client@0.1.0 start /home/tarunmanchukonda/Desktop/UrbanSoal/client

```
react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tarunmanchukonda/.npm/_logs/2019-04-17T15_29_14_257Z-debug.log
tarunmanchukonda@tarunmanchukonda-Inspiron-5558:~/Desktop/UrbanSoal/client$ npm i
Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/tarunmanchukonda/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/0f'Soal/client/nod

Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/tarunmanchukonda/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/9a'home/tarunmanch

Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/tarunmanchukonda/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/59'npmjs.org/multi

Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/tarunmanchukonda/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/0b/dc'les-sc

Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/tarunmanchukonda/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/67/e9'p/UrbanSoal/cli

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tarunmanchukonda/.npm/_logs/2019-04-17T15_29_54_896Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try `npm install`

Comment: Are you running `react-scripts`? That's usually not a global command. Try `npm run start` or `npx react-scripts start`.

Answer (score 0):

Node modules is not installed. And when you are trying to install it, the user doesn't have the permission to write files into the directory.

Try by changing the permissions of the directory

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <directory_name>/
```

Or

Try by giving the current user access to all the files in the folder.

```
sudo chown -R <your username> <directory_name>
```

Then, run `npm install`.